# Sharing Installing Ubuntu with an NTFS data partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs

Will I be allowed to install Ubuntu on to a 1.5gig HDD of which half of the drive is dedicated to an NTFS data partition, no OS is installed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

- Ubuntu must be installed on a filesystem that support permissions (ext is the current default choice). That includes root, boot, home. It can not (and will not) install on NTFS (or FAT for that matter).
- Directories inside /home/$USER/ can be mounted by a system that is NTFS or even symlinked to a partition that is NTFS.

  If by whatever reason the partition is not mounted and required for the system to function properly you will end up with a non bootable system or the system will try to repair itself where the NTFS mount is ignored (with all kinds of problems as a result of that).

  So I myself would use a dedicated partition set up as NTFS and mount it with a different directory and leave /home as it is.